# Webpack Behind Nginx In Subdirectory Websocket not Connecting

Tags: nginx, webpack, webpack-dev-server, nginx-reverse-proxy, webpack-5

I am unable to get the Webpack Dev Server Websocket to connect when running behind Nginx AND in a subdirectory.  For instance, webpack dev server running at http://localhost:8000 but trying to get to it at https://mydom.com/docs

I feel like I've tried every combination of settings possible.

Nginx: 1.22

Webpack: 5.89.0

Here is my Nginx config for the /docs route:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
```

And the relevant part of my Webpack config:

```
devServer: {
  client: {
    webSocketURL: "auto://0.0.0.0:0/docs/ws",
  },
  host: "0.0.0.0",
  port: 8000,
},
```

The page comes up just fine - but auto reload doesn't work and Firefox outputs this in the console:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://mydom.com/docs/ws
```

Please help.

Comment: Is there a bug in how you've formatted your config? According to the documentation at https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#websocketurl you should be using a client URL with port 8000 or a host config, but not both. In particular, your host*name* and port should be under websocketurl, not under devServer.

Comment: The "host" and "port" are what ip address and port the dev server is actually going to run on (see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhost ).  That part is working fine (I can access the pages from the dev server).  The client/webSocketURL is what ip/port/dir the _browser_ is going to try to access the websocket on.  The zeros mean that it will use the same ip/port that the browser is already connected to for the devserver.